# SELECT column FROM table WHERE number FALL-IN-RANGE-OF-TEXT

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

Say, we have a column **'pointer'** in table **'mark'**. In the column, we have some records (TEXT) as follow.

```
1. 0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500
2. 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000
3. 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500
```

Is there a way to select the record (text) where a number (int) fall in the range?

There are 2 scenarios here.

**Case 1:**
Given number *250*, SELECT should return *record 1*.

**Case 2:**
Given number *1000*, SELECT should return *record 3*.

Comment: Are those ranges 0-100, 200-300, 400-500 or 0-500? It's highly ambiguous..

Comment: The ranges are dynamic, but its in sequential order.

Comment: What does this mean exactly? To use mathematical notation, does row 1 represent ([0;100] ∪ [200;300] ∪ [400;500]) or ([0;500])

Comment: In your word, it is [0;500].

Comment: Are always 6 "fields" in mark?

Comment: Oh not so, some can have more or less than that. But say if it is fixed, is there a way out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use SQLite's built-in SQL functions to extract the last number from a variable-sized list.

You should change your table to store the minimum and maximum values in separate columns; then you can simply do

```sql
SELECT * FROM mark WHERE x BETWEEN pointerMin AND pointerMax
```

Comment: I believe adding additional 2 columns is the best solution. Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is by far the craziest SQL that I've written.

```
SELECT pointer, 250 as X
FROM mark 
WHERE CAST(SUBSTR(pointer, 0, LENGTH(pointer) - LENGTH(LTRIM(pointer, "0123456789")) + 1) AS INT) <= X AND
X < CAST(SUBSTR(pointer, LENGTH(RTRIM(pointer, "0123456789"))) AS INT)
```

It uses `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` to remove the first or last numbers and then do some length math to figure out the substring index.

It actually works, too.

Still, I would strongly advise you to rethink your database design.

Comment: This is an interesting solution and in fact it answers my question the best. Sorry that I still decided to pick @CL. solution over this because it makes the whole picture so clear. =)

Answer (score 0):

Lack of built-in backwards `INSTR` makes this query insane!!!

For exactly 6 fields, it would be like:

```
SELECT ROWID FROM mark WHERE 250 >= CAST(SUBSTR(pointer,1, INSTR(pointer, ",")-1) AS
INT) AND 250<CAST(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(pointer,INSTR(pointer,",")+1),
INSTR(SUBSTR(pointer,INSTR(pointer,",")+1),",")+1), INSTR(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(pointer,
INSTR(pointer,",")+1),INSTR(SUBSTR(pointer,INSTR(pointer,",")+1),",")+1),",")+1),
INSTR(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(pointer,INSTR(pointer,",")+1),INSTR(SUBSTR(pointer,
INSTR(pointer,",")+1),",")+1),INSTR(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(pointer,INSTR(pointer,",")+1),
INSTR(SUBSTR(pointer,INSTR(pointer,",")+1),",")+1),",")+1),",")+1),INSTR(SUBSTR(
SUBSTR(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(pointer,INSTR(pointer,",")+1),INSTR(SUBSTR(pointer,
INSTR(pointer,",")+1),",")+1),INSTR(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(pointer,INSTR(pointer,",")+1),
INSTR(SUBSTR(pointer,INSTR(pointer,",")+1),",")+1),",")+1),INSTR(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(
SUBSTR(pointer,INSTR(pointer,",")+1),INSTR(SUBSTR(pointer,INSTR(pointer,",")+1)
,",")+1),INSTR(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(pointer,INSTR(pointer,",")+1),INSTR(SUBSTR(pointer,
INSTR(pointer,",")+1),",")+1),",")+1),",")+1),",")+1) AS INT);
```

I suggest you to use a temporary table computed problematically INSTEAD of this...

Comment: I have a suspicion that INSTR doesn't exist on Android.. (it was added to SQLite last December)

Comment: Yeah, it is not there.